# Letter spacing on React Native - Android

Tags: react-native

I'm using React Native 0.29 with Android emulator (API Level 23). I am trying to achieve `letterSpacing` on `Text` component. But it seems not working on Android. Official documentation says that it only works in iOS. Is there any workaround of this problem?

Answer (score 28):

The lack of letter spacing on Android can be "solved" by adding one or more spaces between each character. I have found the unicode `HAIR_SPACE U+200A` to give the best results, but you might have to experiment to find what suits best for your font. For example 2 hair spaces or one `U+2009 THIN SPACE`.

`function applyLetterSpacing(string, count = 1) {
  return string.split('').join('\u200A'.repeat(count));
}`

It probably works best for headers and menu labels.

Unicode spaces: https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html

Comment: This works well for smaller type, but for headlines it is still too wide. Is there something thinner than hair space? I was looking around, but could not find anything. A pixel space?

Comment: One problem is with longer (breaking) texts the text can break after each character (because there is a space). Has anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 15):

you can give space between letter using default props of Text component.Like

```
<Text style={{ fontSize: 18, letterSpacing: 3, color: '#FFFFFF' }}>Stack Overflow</Text>
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like as of React Native 0.30 [letterSpacing](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#letterspacing) is iOS only as well. You could always add this and issue a pull request :)

Another option might be to hack together a function that takes a string and adds spacing around each letter. (it would be a hack though!)

Answer (score 2):

Update React Native to at least version [0.55](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#055) for letter spacing on Android to work.

Answer (score 0):

letter Spacing prop of text would help in giving space between letters in a word. The code is as as follows
`<Text style={{  letterSpacing: 3 }}>Your Text</Text>`